# Logical Address to Physical Address in Page Table

Tags: virtual, memory-address

I really dont know where to start in the following question and how scoured the internet for hints.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or let me know a way of tackling this question it would be great.

Explain clearly how a logical address is
translated to a physical address in a computer system that uses a two level
page table with the following details:

Each address has 32 bits.
The lower order 16 bits are used as the offset.
The higher order 16 bits are divided into two parts of 8 bits each for
accessing the two-level page tables.

What is the total number of pages possible in the virtual memory of this
computer? What is the size of a page?

I understand the following but cant really go any further:

The logical address is generated by the CPU and divided into:

A page number which is used as an index in a page table which contains
the base address of each page in physical memory.

The page offset combined with the base address is then used to define the
physical memory address that is sent to the memory unit.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to read is the Memory chapter from `Modern Operating System 2'nd or 3'rd edition` by `A.S.Tanenbaum`. He explains the 2 level memory allocation and I believe it will answer your questions.